# Nordic 8001 development

Tags: bluetooth

I'm trying to get a nordic 8001 eval board for an embedded application.  I'v got an iPhone app shell up and running that discovers/connects to Bluetooth devices in the area. I've been able to discover BlueRadio,BlueGiga, Panasonic radio modules. I'm also able to discover the Nordic 8001 sample board fron the $99 eval kit, with the 8002 board from the same kit, all without the $399 demo board. I've also got my embedded processor a Cypress Semiconductor PSoC3  responding to the device_startup_event from the 8001 board only. The issue I'm having is that the next step talks about setting configuration set by nRFgo Studio. 
Question:
Does the nRF8001 come preprogrammed with some predefined configuration options that need to be set up, if so what are they. If not how do I go about determine what needs to pe programmed and how do I do it. I can't seem to find detail document on this or on programming the 8001 board by itself.

Comment: What's a "nordic 8001 eval board"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe there is an evaluation board for the 8001

The configuration done by the nRFgo Studio is actually setting up a Local/Remote service database, in addition to the security settings of the device, and then generating a header file with configuration packages that you send to the nRF8001.

You would have to send all of those configuration commands to the nRF8001 for it to use the profile created in nRFgo Studio.

By downloading the nRF8001-SDK you can use the sample profile configuration header files, in case you are not able to use the nRFgo Studio. But to be able to create your own profiles you would have to use the nRFgo Studio. There are some examples that is precompiled for the nRF8200 that is in the nRF8001 Development kit, but not sure if there is any examples for your choice of microcontroller.
http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-R-low-energy/nRF8001-SDK

After this you would have to set the device in connectable mode (or bondable mode) depending on what type of operation you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm porting the Cypress PSoC3. I have the nRF8001-SDK development kit and it came with (1) nRF2740 nRF8001 eval board with PCB antenna, (1) nRF2741 nRF8001 eval board w/o antenna. and (1) nRF 2735 nRF8002 eval board which has connectorization to the nRF8001 boards. I was hoping just to be able to create a data file that could be read in as a structure from my code but it sounds a bit more complicated than that. I talked to Nordic about the programming part of this and unless I want to write my own SPI programmer from my chip I'm better off giving in and purchasi

Comment: If you are able to receive the startup message then you should be able to send commands and receive other messages from the nRF8001, you can try to download [nRFGo Studio](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRFgo-Studio) and use the header files generated. You can also use studio to configure the nRF8002 (via usb) but that one only have a limited number of profiles embedded. (Can configure device name and how the led blinks + buttons)

Comment: Thanks Palhaland for the follow up. Here's my current status. I am receiving the DeviceStartedEvent(Setup) and able to successfully send out commandGetTemperature and commandGet battery commands with proper CommandResponseEvent including valid data.

Comment: Next step (where i am now) is to send out valid setup data. From your response and David's response it sound like I can use one of the sample configuration file and set this data out. Am I right in understanding that this is the setup data?

Comment: Basic goal right now is to just open up a pipe to iPhone app that I have written and get a connection established so I can release the ACI microcontroller hardware interface (PSoC3).

Comment: I'm OK with buying $399 kit after this to create my own profile. Right now I'm a little gun shy sine I've purchase two other vendor kits only to decide for one reason or another to go another path. The Nordic right now definitely seems like the path for me to go, but I just want to make sure. Thanks again for the help. Gary

Comment: So I guess what the $64,000 dollar question is what is 1. I assume the 'sample profile configuration file is the .xml file in teh project directory.

Comment: 2. What is the structure of the setup data going out?    I assume that the nRF8001 assume a certain sequence and size befoe it will issue the DeviceStartedEvent(standby(0x81 0x03 0x00 0x02). I have not found details in the data sheet as to what order the configuration data sent and how to tell the 8001 what the data is. for example can I send out hardware setup info before GATT or GAP. OR... is it as simple as sending out th entire .xml file itself (formatting and data) in ascii format?

Comment: The sample profile configuration xml file is the one that you load on to the nRFGo Studio, and it will generate a set of header files that you can use. It generates a multidimentional array with setup commands and you send the first packet sequence in that one, then you receive a command status event with continue as status. and you send the next one, until you receive the command response success. After that you will receive a new device started event and you would be good to go to send the connect command

Comment: I've got it all straight now, I generated the raw data file by dragging the xml file to the batch file in the project directory. This created a uBlue_info file with the required setup data for setup commands.